# C++ error: default template arguments may not be used in function template

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, default-parameters, function-template

I am trying to understand what the value = T() means and how to fix it. Also the function is a constructor for a class.

```
template<typename T>
Accumulator<T>::Accumulator(const T& value = T())
{
     total = value;
}
```

This does not compile the following errors are:

```
error: default argument given for parameter 1 of `Accumulator<T>::Accumulator(const T&)'
error: after previous specification in `Accumulator<T>::Accumulator(const T&)'
```

Basically the function is a constructor for a class with a default argument that sets "total" a private variable of my class to "value" if given a value for an argument.

Comment: Looks like the original function declaration (in the class) didn't have the default argument.

Comment: `= T()` should be *only* a part of declaration if it is not an in-class definition

Comment: I tried removing the =T() however I was given link errors.

Comment: is the constructor's definition in header file or cpp file?

Comment: It is in a cpp file and I am not suppose to change the header file.

Comment: templates must be entirely in header file unless you are using explicit instantiation

Comment: I am suppose to define this function in a separate file, the function I posted above was copied and pasted from the header file.

Comment: @John why are you *supposed to define this function in separate file* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only specify the default parameter in the function declaration, in the header.

Comment: Okay I think i understand what you mean. The default arguments should be assigned in the earliest occurrence of a function definition. So removing the '= T()' should fix it but I get link errors now.

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant.